# Making glibc system calls from C#

Tags: c#, mono, glibc, libc

I would like to call `execl()` from my Mono application.  Here is the declaration:

```
[DllImport("libc.so.6")]
private static extern int execl( string path, string argv );
```

Then, where `pathname` and `arguments` are standard C# string objects:

```
execl(pathname, pathname + " " + arguments);
```

The `execl()` call is not working, however, and if I fetch the error info with `perror()`, I'm seeing "Bad Address".

I've been assured by the documentation that Mono/C# automagically converts Strings to the required c-style null terminated strings, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

What is the proper way to make system calls from C#/Mono?  Should I be using an array of C#'s `sbyte` types followed by `\0`?

Answer (score 2):

On my x64 system

> Linux DNA-NOTEBOOK 3.18.2-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 9 07:37:51 CET
>   2015 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> Mono JIT compiler version 3.12.0 (tarball Thu Jan 15 18:46:56 UTC
>   2015).

The following code runs fine

```
[DllImport("libc.so.6")]
private static extern int execl(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string path, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string argv);

public static void Main()
{
    execl("/usr/bin/bash", string.Empty);
}
```

What version of mono are you running? Also can you get us the debug information or post a trace somewhere?